# Is there a term for "recognition anxiety" such as when you recognize but can't remember the name of someone in a movie?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm sure there must be a more pithy term for when you recognize someone in a movie, TV show or real life, but can't remember their name or where you recognize them from.

Specifically, it's more than just "on the tip of my tongue" because there's that overwhelming need to stop everything else to resolve it.

Comment: If you cannot recall the precise word for something, you have a case of lethologica, which may lead you to an obsession with trying to recall it—loganamnosis.

Comment: *Recognition memory* has two modes: data about an entity require *recollection*, but another linkage seems to govern *familiarity* (knowledge that the entity, and therefore data related to it, are stored somewhere; even if not accessible).  Your need to recall is probably due to what that data may mean to the new encounter, or simply the desire to store new data near old for the sake of future recall.